# How to customise title on Wordpress (running Yoast)

Tags: php, wordpress, yoast

I am trying to customise a title for a Wordpress page. In the page I have some php to obtain data from the database. I would like to output a custom title based on the data and the page id. I have tried this:

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'property_title', 10, 1);
function property_title() {
global $post;
$postid = $post->ID;
if ($postid == '72616') {
   $title['title'] = "Property number $propertyid";
   return $title;
}
}
```

How can I check the postid and if it is the right page, output the data from the sql query?

Many thanks,

Neil.

Comment: Where is `$propertyid` coming from ?

Comment: The page is initially called with `www.domain.com/property/?reference=12345` and then I have the php call `$propertyid = $_GET["reference"];` within the page. It outputs ok (e.g. `echo "Property ID: $propertyid"` on the page but not in the `<title></title>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

The title is passed in for that filter. Make sure you return title outside of the if statement.

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'property_title', 10, 1);

function property_title($title) {
   global $post;

   $propertyid = get_query_var('reference');

   $postid = $post->ID;
   if ($postid == '72616') {
      $title = "Property number $propertyid";
   }
   return $title;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_property_query_vars' );

function add_property_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'reference';

    return $query_vars;
}
```

Comment: That partly works. Thank you. The only problem is that it does not pass across `$propertyid` or other variables such as `$location_area`. How can I pass the page variables (the result of a query on the database, e.g. `$location_area = $row["area"];`) to the function? They output ok in the page but not between the `<title></title>` tags.

Comment: Edited. I'm pretty sure get_query_var works in filters. Try not to use `get` as it is insecure.

Comment: Returns nothing.

Comment: My fault, i assumed the query var was registered. Try adding that filter.

Comment: This works in the case of `$propertyid` which comes from the URL `www.domain.com/property/?reference=12345` but it does not work in the case of `$location_area = $row["area"]` which is pulled from an sql query to a mySQL database with `mysqli_connect`. How can I pass the `$location_area` to the `<title></title>`? Thx

Comment: Can you post the code you use to get that? You'll either need to get that information in this function most likely.